# SQLite Error 5:

Tags: php, sql, raspbian

I'm running SQLite and PHP on my Raspberry Pi.

I made a form s
where users can edit their data (firstname, password, etc.).

Therefore I use PDOs. Whenever I try to execute the followin command, I get the SQLite Error 5: Database is locked!

But in fact, there is no other connection to the database.

Here's the command:

$userDB->exec("UPDATE user SET passwort = '".$password."', vorname = '".$vorname."', nachname = '".$nachname."', email = '".$email."' WHERE username = '".$username."'");

The interesting thing is, that on another page, nearly the same command is executing without problems.

Btw, there are several other PHP-scripts on this page with DB-connections, but I closed all by setting them NULL.

Anyone knows a solution for this?

Comment: NB: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. You should not concatenate user provided data into an SQL string. Use prepared statements instead.

Comment: Are you closing the existing connections with `sqlite_close($userDB);` ?

Comment: @Gadget no, because I'm actually using PDOs.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I found a solution.

I forgot to close the result set!

That means, if I do a query, I will get a result set and at the end of the page, I must use this command: $result->closeCursor(); and $result=null;

And that's it!